# Prestashop Contact-Form Subject

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, prestashop

In My prestashop contact-form there is exist this code

`SELECT *
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'contact c
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'contact_lang cl ON c.id_contact = cl.id_contact
        WHERE cl.id_lang = '.(int)($id_lang).'
        ORDER BY name ASC`

which create this query

`SELECT * 
FROM  ava_contact c
LEFT JOIN  ava_contact_lang cl ON c.id_contact = cl.id_contact 
WHERE cl.id_lang =6
ORDER BY  name ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30`

and it displaying normal result

[image: nomral query result]

but when DB class executing this code

`Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('SELECT *
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'contact c
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'contact_lang cl ON c.id_contact = cl.id_contact
        WHERE cl.id_lang = '.(int)($id_lang).'
        ORDER BY name ASC');`

all values displayed except in 'name' field, all values there are empty string, hmm,, which is wrong part?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit strange, in my Prestashop 1.4.6 contact form, form subject doesn't shown when it changed in other language.

[image: Prestashop strange behavior]

I've spent some days to find for solutions and the problem resolved with deleting some white spaces in `getContacts` method (..\shop\classes)

[image: clearing white spaces]

and the result was

[image: form subject displayed]